# Passing an argument using execvp

Tags: c, gcc, fork, execvp

I have this in my parent.c file

```
int main()
{
int n = 6;
int pid;
int status;
char* command = "./child";
for (i=1; i<=n; i++){


    if((pid = fork()) == 0) {
        execvp(command, NULL);
    }
    wait(&status);
}
```

My child.c file looks like this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *processnum = argv[0];
    printf("This is the child %s\n", processnum);
    return 0;
}
```

I basically just ran

gcc -o parent parent.c

gcc -o child child.c

./parent

This prints outs "This is the child (null)" 6 times, which is what I expect. But I want to be able to pass a parameter as I run child, in this case the process number.

So I changed my parent.c to look like this

```
for (i=1; i<=n; i++){
    if(i == 1){
        char* args = "1";
    }
    if(i == 2){
        char* args = "2";
    }
    if(i == 3){
        char* args = "3";
    }
    if(i == 4){
        char* args = "4";
    }
    if(i == 5){
        char* args = "5";
    }
    if(i == 6){
        char* args = "6";
    }

    if((pid = fork()) == 0) {
        execvp(command, args);
    }
    wait(&status);
}
```

What I thought would happen is that my program would print "This is the child 1", "This is the child 2" etc...

However, what actually happened is that the program seemed to run parent.c numerous times (I put a print statement at the start of parent.c and the output printed that statement like 20 times) instead of child.c

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Is there another way I can pass a parameter to child.c?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you expecting the value of `argv[0]` to be `0` or `1`? The manual page for `execvp` explains how to pass arguments. What you're pasing is incorrect. It expects `char *argv[]` (an pointer to an array of argument pointers). As an aside, your string of `if` statements would be cleaner done as a `switch` statement.

Comment: Originally I tried setting command = "./child 6" for example, I was hoping argv[0] would store 6 and I would be able to use that in the child but it did not work

Comment: If you read the documentation for `execvp` it should clarify things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your program as it stands. First, as described by others, the second argument to execvp is a char ** type ... it ends up as the argv in the exec'ed program.

Second, the 
    if(i == 1){
        char* args = "1";
    }
    ...
code sets a variable args whose scope ends at the next line. You must declare the args in a scope in which you want to use it.

Third, converting a number to a string like this is very limited and tedious! You would do better using the standard C function sprintf (or even better snprintf).

Here is an updated parent.c:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
        int n = 6;
        int pid;
        int status;
        char* command = "./child";
        char *child_args[2];
        char number_buff[32];   // more than big enough to hold any number!

        child_args[1] = NULL;
        for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
                sprintf(number_buff, "%d", i);
                child_args[0] = number_buff;
                if((pid = fork()) == 0) {
                        execvp(command, child_args);
                }
                wait(&status);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
here is the critical excerpt from the man page for execvp()

   The execv(), execvp(), and execvpe()  functions  provide  an  array  of
   pointers  to  null-terminated  strings that represent the argument list
   available to the new  program.   The  first  argument,  by  convention,
   should  point  to the filename associated with the file being executed.
   The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer.
```

Answer (score -1):

> Can anyone explain why this is happening? Is there another way I can pass a parameter to child.c?

You should be passing a char* array to execvp, not a char*. As mentioned in the comments, the last element of the array should be a null pointer. The following should work:

```
char* args[] = {"1\0", NULL};
execvp(command, args);
```

I'm guessing that execvp is failing since it can't dereference args as a char**, and thus the forked process is continuing the loop as a parent. You should be checking the return value of execvp to see that the function call worked.

Also, command and args should be null-terminated. I suggest using the function `itoa` to convert an int to a c string.

Comment: the parameter(s)  passed to execvp() are:  1) path/name of file to execute 2) the number of entries in the passed third parameter 3) a ppointer to an array of pointers to C strings, with the last entry being NULL.